# Why does moment.tz work different depending on how your import it?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, momentjs

This line works.

`console.log(moment(), moment().tz("America/New_York"));`

While this one fails.

`console.log(moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York"));`

They are right next to each other. Yet the second one is an example on the main page (http://momentjs.com/timezone/) and works if you paste it into the console.

I'm using require.js in a backbone app to import the script.

Any ideas on what's wrong? The fact that the first one succeeds makes me think that the scripts have loaded properly thus making the second failure inexplicable, but I'm not sure.

Comment: [RequireJS-specific how-to](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/use-it/require-js/) probably trumps general usage examples?

Answer (score 0):

After taking a break and looking at the documentation again, the proper method of using moment by itself is to define the path as "moment".

When using with the timezone library though, both libraries have to be imported but only the timezone library should point to moment.

```
e.g. 

define([
   path/path/moment, 
   path/path/moment-timezone]) , 

function( notUsed,moment) { moment.tz(...) }


define([
   path/path/moment, 
   ]) , 

function( moment) { moment.(...) }
```